# Preposition вокруг (+ genitive) but sentence only has accusative nouns

Tags: падежи, предлоги

I have a sentence,

> Он видел вокруг красивые, живописные места, невысокие горы, леса, реку Волгу.

and translating is not hard, and I think the meaning is,

> He saw beautiful, picturesque places, short mountains, forests around the Volga river.

Now I looked up the preposition (or adverb?) `вокруг` and I see that two sources say the `genitive` case comes afterwards. So I see that the forests, mountains and places are `direct objects` of the verb `видел`, hence `accusative`, and I think these objects are seen *around* the river, so these latter words (adj. and noun river) should be `genitive`...?

I guess that, due to some freedom in word order, that the sentence could also be written as(?),

> Он видел красивые, живописные места, невысокие горы, леса, вокруг реку Волгу.

which more clearly (correctly?) associates the river to the preposition.

So why not,

> Он видел вокруг красивые, живописные места, невысокие горы, леса, реки Волги.

as the proper sentence?

Comment: Why do people answer questions and not vote them up? So strange)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Он видел вокруг **красивые, живописные места, невысокие горы, леса, реку Волгу**.

The accusative is correct, he saw (what?). **Вокруг** here is an adverb, not a preposition.

Saw (where?) around, or nearby– вокруг. It isn't connected with the direct object in the accusative. Compare it with the following, where вокруг is a preposition

> Земля вращается вокруг солнца

Вокруг (чего?) солнца (genitive).A preposition can't stand far from the noun it belongs to. So, if it (вокруг) were a preposition, ( the nearest noun is места), but the sentence wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning is

> He saw beautiful, picturesque places, short mountains, forests, the Volga river around himself.

And no, the word order is not SO free.

Comment: wish they would have wrote: "...вокруг себя..." so I would have known it was "around himself".

Comment: @nate *"Он видел вокруг..."* is translated as *"He saw ... around himself".* *Himself* is assumed, since no other information is provided. *"Он видел вокруг реки Волги..."* would be translated as *"He saw ... around Volga river"*. It's similar to English *"He looked around"*, which is understood as *"He looked around himself".*